# creating my first liferay portlet(maven) and I get an error when I deploy

Tags: eclipse, maven, liferay, portlet

I'm new to liferay, i've created my first liferay portlet!

[Project](https://i.gyazo.com/b62506405d9b846b55a58df1c77da8e9.png)

However, when I right click on my project and go to

Liferay > Maven > liferay:deploy

I get this error

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 55, column 13
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-bridges:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 61, column 13
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-taglib:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 67, column 13
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-java:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 73, column 13
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${liferay.maven.plugin.version}'. @ line 15, column 14
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example.plugins:try:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\otaibit.ENDLAB\workspace\try\pom.xml) has 5 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:portal-service:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 55, column 13
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-bridges:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 61, column 13
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-taglib:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 67, column 13
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.liferay.portal:util-java:jar must be a valid version but is '${liferay.version}'. @ line 73, column 13
[ERROR]     'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.liferay.maven.plugins:liferay-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is '${liferay.maven.plugin.version}'. @ line 15, column 14
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously missing the `${liferay.version}` property one way or another. You can set this up in a parent POM, in your pom or in general settings - it's all [well documented](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/using-liferay-maven-parent-plugin-projects) with a full sample parent pom, links to further documentation.

I'm aware that it's discouraged to just link to the documentation here, but I believe that this answer would otherwise be followed up with another question on more configuration for the liferay-maven plugin and mirroring the documentation here would just be too much.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create Maven Profile.
It should be defined either in your pom.xml or Maven/Settings/conf.xml

Example of one of my Profile.

```
<profile>
<id>lr7</id>
<properties>
 <liferay.version>7.0.0</liferay.version>
 <liferay.maven.plugin.version>7.0.0</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
 <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>E:\lr-train\DXP\liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-ga1\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
 <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>E:\lr-train\DXP\liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-ga1\tomcat-8.0.32\webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
 <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>E:\lr-train\DXP\liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-ga1\tomcat-8.0.32\lib\ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
 <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>E:\lr-train\DXP\liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-7.0-ga1\tomcat-8.0.32\webapps\ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
</properties>
</profile>
```

Now you can either specify the profile while deploying
i.e mvn clean package liferay:deploy -PprofileName

Or you can set Active profile

```
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

Even in eclipse you can specify the profile.
Whenever you create a project, that time you need to specify the profile

Eclipse provides the option to either create by specifying server or selecting profile
Also on clicking on maven project you can specify the profile. 
[image: Selecting maven profile]